# Featuretools handling of multiple join keys

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

How are one to many relationships with multiple join keys represented in featuretools? Is there some integrated approach - or should the join keys manually be concatenated into a single column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is to concatenate the keys into a single column.

This is typically done as a preprocessing step in Pandas before the DataFrame is loaded into Featuretools.